# Completely lost on an issue with timezones using Pytz and Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pytz

I'm currently working on a report using PANDAS that takes data from an API and formats it for some people. The main issue revolves around a column called "Status Date". This column pulls data from two API fields: one that displays when an application is filed, and one that displays when the application is awarded. As of right now we're just dealing with filed scholarships, and I have code written that merges the two fields based on which one is null:

```
merged.loc[merged["Status Date"].isnull(),'Status Date'] = merged["Categorized At"]
```

This does the job. However, both API fields are hardcoded with UTC+0000.

This is an issue, because out UTC offset is -0600 and the API pulls in +0000. This would cause an issue where any scholarships filed (the data we're working with) after 18:00:00 would be categorized into the next day. For example:

```
Status Date
12/5/20
```

when it should be:

```
Status Date
12/4/20
```

To fix this, I used Pytz to write a code that would turn anything in this column into a DateTime object and localize it:

```
merged['Status Date'] = pd.to_datetime(merged['Status Date'], errors='coerce')
merged['Status Date'] = merged['Status Date'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('America/Chicago').dt.date
```

However, this managed to create new issues. While anything that was categorized after 18:00:00 (like the above example) was fixed, there are now some dates that are pulling the previous date. For example:

```
Status Date
1/4/21
```

should be

```
Status Date
1/5/21
```

I'm completely lost with how to fix this. I can't tell if there's any major issues with my code, and we need this fixed soon.

Comment: the examples are hard to track if they only contain dates I think. could you add the hours as well?

Comment: @MrFuppes unfortunately the date is all I have access to at the moment, which makes this more frustrating

Comment: Ok, the you have to keep in mind that a default time 00:00:00 will be added if it is not supplied.

Comment: @MrFuppes is there anything I could add to the code to address this?

Comment: Are you sure that your input data doesn't contain a time  associated with the date? It wouldn't make sense to me to store *only dates*, if conversion to another time zone is required later on

Comment: @MrFuppes you're right, there's a time associated with it, but the time is defaulting to 00:00:00 for some reason

Comment: if you convert UTC to UTC-6 and the time is 00:00 hours, you'll always end up on the day before with the date